# Does it need to socket.leave() a room on disconnect in Socket.io?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

In `socket.io`, Do I need to manually call `socket.leave()` when disconnect fires?
or `NodeJs Socket.io` itself handles it?

```
socket.on("disconnect" function() {
   this.leave("room"); // is this necessary?
});
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

**No**, all rooms are already left before emitting this event.

[Code from `socket.io`](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/blob/54ff591b07ad17915ffd9f325448e72c9a76e828/lib/socket.js#L432):

```
Socket.prototype.onclose = function(reason){
  if (!this.connected) return this;
  debug('closing socket - reason %s', reason);
  this.emit('disconnecting', reason);
  this.leaveAll();   //leaving all rooms
  this.nsp.remove(this);
  this.client.remove(this);
  this.connected = false;
  this.disconnected = true;
  delete this.nsp.connected[this.id];
  this.emit('disconnect', reason);   //emitting event
};
```

Answer (score 4):

No you dont need to manually call socket.leave() when disconnect event fires.
see http://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/ for more details